# Converting Floating Point to Integer?

Tags: raster, arcmap

I'm trying to build a raster attribute table since my DEM file does not have one. But I can't because the file is using a floating point.

How do I convert the floating point into an integer?

I'm using the elevation data to do a least cost path analysis afterwards.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/263128/2856

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the attribute table of raster data, you need to convert the Pixel Type from floating point to signed integer. This can be done if you have Spatial Analyst extension.

With `Spatial Analyst` you can use `Raster Calculator` to convert the Pixel type from floating point to signed integer using the following formula:

```
Int(RoundDown("YourRasterImage"))     # You can use RoundUp() also, it is up to you
```

The raster data with a pixel type of floating point, the attribute table is not active:

[image]

After converting the pixel type to signed integer using the above formula, the attribute table becomes active:

[image]

Here is the attribute table:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think @ahmadhanb's answer is very solid. Alternatively you can also try the [int](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/int.htm) tool as I assume that you have Spatial Analyst license. The tool will convert the floating point to integer for you.